# IN_Q_OVERFLOW event not being raised in python inotify

Tags: python, inotify

The inotify system clearly raises an [IN_Q_OVERFLOW](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) event in the event a watcher queue event is raised when the corresponding event queue is full. I'm using the [inotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify) python package to register for inotify events.  I'm interested in knowning when the IN_Q_OVERFLOW event is raised but it would appear the inotify package is ignoring this event entirely.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to register for this event via inotify or another python package that provides this behaviour?

Snippet from inotify adapter.py

```
def __handle_inotify_event(self, wd, event_type):
    """Handle a series of events coming-in from inotify."""

        ....
        if path is None:
            break #if i print header.mask i clearly see 16384 or 0x00004000 the IN_Q_OVERFLOW bit
        yield (header, type_names, path, filename)
```

code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution -  [pyinotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinotify)! adding characters to get to 30...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out watchman:
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/

There is a python client included, but not much documentation about using it from Python.   I'd recommend looking at the implementation of the watchman-wait and watchman-make tools

Watchman works a little differently from most file watching systems in that it maintains a consistent view of the directory tree that you're watching.  It will internally handle overflow events and pass on the information about them.  By default it will just tell you that all files might have changed, so you don't need to change your application logic unless you care about discovering files that were deleted during the overflow event.

Disclaimer: I created and maintain watchman

Comment: Is this python?  Unfortunately, i need a lightweight python wrapper.  I suspect this doesn't fit the bill

Comment: There's a service process that you can talk to using python.  The service process takes care of a number of tricky cases.  The python portion is lightweight; it talks to the service over a unix socket.